# Rails: How do I use hidden_field in a form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hidden-field

I've read [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M002295), but I'm new to RoR so I'm having a little trouble understanding it. I'm using a form to create a new request record, and all of the variables that I need to send exist already. Here is the data I need to send (this is in a do loop):

```
:user_id => w[:requesteeID]
:requesteeName => current_user.name
:requesteeEmail => current_user.email
:info => e
```

Here's my form, which works so far, but only send NULL values for everything:

```
<% form_for(:request, :url => requests_path) do |f| %>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit e %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

How do I use hidden_fields to send the data I already have? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Just tried <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => w[:calleeID] %> but it just sent NULL

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Ref [hidden_field](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M002295)  or [hidden_field_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M002252)

```
<% form_for(:request, :url => requests_path) do |f| %>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.hidden_field :some_column %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'selected', 'none'  %>
        <%= f.submit e %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

then in controller

```
 params[:selected]="none"
 params[:request][:some_column] = request.some_column
```

Note when you used

```
   <%= f.hidden_field :some_column %>
```

it change to html

```
<input type="hidden" id="request_some_column" name="request[some_column]" value="#{@request.some_column}" />
```

and when you used

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'selected', 'none'  %>
```

it change to html

```
   <input id="selected" name="selected" type="hidden" value="none"/>
```

Answer (score 92):

You can send a custom value as a hidden input for your model like that:

```rb
<%= f.hidden_field :your_model_field_name, value: 12 %>
```

Where `value: 12` is just a demo, but you can pass whatever value you need.

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate more on [Bruno Paulino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31456304/10907864).

I had this same concern when working on a Rails 6 application.

I had a form for books, but I needed to pass in the **current user's id** into the form for each book that will be created in a hidden manner.

My initial form field was this way:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :user_id %>
  <%= form.text_field :user_id %>
</div>
```

I had to modify it to this using this:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.hidden_field :model_field_name, value: field_value %>
</div>
```

So I had this after on:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
</div>
```