# Sending data in my form hidden field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to add a jquery upload
But i need to pass a parameter into my form

Here the form

```
<%= form_for Photo.new do |f|%>
  <%= f.label :title %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :title, :rows => 3, :value => "Add a photo", :onclick=>"this.value='';" %>
  <%= f.file_field :photo, multiple: true %>
  <%= f.hidden_field('event_id', params[:event_id]) %>
  <%= f.submit "Add Picture" %>
<% end %>
```

But this doesn't work, the issue is I have a link has follow
localhost/events/16/photos/useradd

where 16 is the event_id params. How can i place it into my hidden field so it is send afterwards?

UPDATE

```
NoMethodError in Photos#useradd
Showing /home/jean/rail/voix/app/views/photos/useradd.html.erb where line #13 raised:
undefined method `merge' for "16":String
```

that the error and 16 is my event_id

Comment: what exactly didn't work? have you checked the html to see if the hidden field is there? try putting a debugger on your create action and see what's getting there

Comment: Check similar query here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131982/how-do-i-use-hidden-field-in-a-form-for-in-ruby-on-rails/3132007#3132007

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, shot in the dark here:

Try

```
<%= f.hidden_field 'event_id', :value => params[:event_id] %>
```

**Edit - Why it worked:**

The hidden_field method has the following signature: `hidden_field(object_name, method, options = {})` 
[See the docs about hidden_field](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field)

You have passed the value 16 as a method to be called by hidden_field, and that would not work.

The third argument of hidden_field is a options hash. Setting the "value" field of that hash will set the value of the input tag generated by the helper, and thus effectively setting '16' as the value of that form field. :)

Best regards

Comment: Thanks you, i think it will help me a lot