# Rails 4: Updating Database with Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, simple-form

I've got a simple button, which (should) turn the value of a Boolean into true:

```
= simple_form_for @item do |f|
    = f.check_box :is_active, {checked: true} #Hide via CSS, it is actually checked.
    = f.button :submit, 'Publish', class: 'btn'
```

Should that form be inove and I made a mistake in it? Or do I need some Controller Stuff?
When I press that Button, the Boolean stays false.

Thanks in advance for each answer! Please tell me if you need additional information.

Comment: You see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12701287/2144445?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
f.input :is_active, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false
```

In the Readme of the repo in section [Usage](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#usage)

part:

> Simple Form accepts same options as their corresponding input type
>   helper in Rails:

and also in other parts

Comment: The hidden check_box is checked - it somehow does not update the value