# How to use HTML ID in a ruby if statement condition

Tags: html, ruby, if-statement

I'm trying to render a form depending on which checkbox has been ticked. I want to use an if statement with the checkbox's id in the condition, but rails is throwing up an error 'undefined method tab1. Is there a way to target html in an if statement? thanks

```html
<input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label class="label-header" for="tab1"> UK Address</label>

  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label class="label-header"for="tab2"> International Address </label>

  <!-- <section id="content1"> -->
   <% if tab1.checked? %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :address do |fields| %>
     <section id="content1">
       <%= render "address/fields", fields: fields, addressable: addressable %>
      </section>
    <% end %>
   <% else %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :address do |fields| %>
     <section id="content2">
       <%= render "address/international_fields", fields: fields, addressable: addressable %>
      </section>
    <% end %>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: You'll need to use javascript to change your DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails doesn't know that you are trying to reference the `id` field of the DOM objects because that's not something it's looking for.  The reason you are getting that specific error is because ruby is looking at `tab1.checked?` and saying "before I can call `checked?` I need to grab `tab1` so i can call `checked?` on whatever kind of object `tab1` is... Now, do I have a variable or method defined called `tab1`... No?  Then I'm going to throw an error because as far as I know it's undefined".  Basically, it's not Ruby's job to think about HTML element IDs (in this context).

If you want to pull information from the DOM you should use Javascript.  There is a separation of concerns to understand here.  Think of it as if you are telling Rails to render everything when the view loads, then conditionally showing and hiding the sections using Javascript events.

here is an example:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='foo' checked>
<label for='foo'>Foo Questions</label>

<input type='checkbox' id='bar'>
<label for='bar'>Bar Questions</label>

<%= form_for :my_model do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :foo_questions %>
   <%= f.input :bar_questions %>
   <%= f.submit 'submit me' %>
<%= end %>
```

And then in your related Javascript file something like...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var fooQuestions = $('#foo_questions');
   var barQuestions = $('#bar_questions');

   $('#foo').on('click', function() {
      fooQuestions.show();
      barQuestions.hide();
   });

   $('#bar').on('click', function() {
      fooQuestions.hide();
      barQuestions.show();
   });

});
```

Keep in mind that even if you hide one of your questions, the value of that hidden form field will still be submitted with the form.  If you are trying to submit different data sets then there is a good chance you are trying to do too much with one model.  Or, if you really want to make it work you could use Javascript to take the responses from text boxes outside the form, pull the value that is entered and set it to a hidden form element inside the form.  But that might be beyond the scope, so I'll just point you to this article...

[This appears to be a good post on how to use hidden inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131982/how-do-i-use-hidden-field-in-a-form-for-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: thanks for your answer. this sort of works, however on the first load of the page, both forms are displaying, one on top of each other, as i havent clicked on a tab at that point. is there a way to get around that? thanks

Comment: You could use the same logic to simply hide one of the elements on page load. So right below `var barQuestions = $('#bar_questions');`  simply add `barQuestions.hide();`.  This will run without waiting for a click event when the page loads.  It's worth noting there are other, arguably better ways to do this using CSS and classes assigned by rails, but for now this should do the trick. : )